# Get user data in request.user using express and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prism

I'm trying to create a middleware to ensure the user is admin, but when I print `request.customer`, the result is **undefined**.

This is what I'm doing:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

import { prisma } from "../../prisma";

export async function ensureAdmin(
  request: Request,
  response: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  const { id } = request.customer;
  const customer = await prisma.customer.findUnique({
    where: {
      id,
    },
  });

  console.log(request.customer);

  return next();
}
```

`request.customer` returns this: `Property 'customer' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'`
So I declared the express namespace by adding the customer id, like this:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    customer: {
      id: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no errors but at the same time when I print `request.customer` it comes undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to correctly implement the middleware as it is described in this documentation: [Using middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

There you will have the `(req, res, next)` function. The req is of type Request and contains parameters for query parameters (called via `req.params`), headers (called via `req.headers['...']`) and many more. Wherever your customer id is encoded, you need to extract it from your request.

Answer (score 0):

I just find a way to tell typescript how to understand request object with new properties on it. This is the way:

```js
interface AuthRequest extends Request {
    customer: string
}

const auth = async (req: AuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // Do you staff here...and then add customer to req object
    req.customer = 'id of administrator user'
    next()
}
```

Finish line, you have to extend Express Request interface with your custom properties and then use that new interface instead Express Request interface.
Have a nice day.